# Change Touch Menu Items in Compass Sample

Tags: google-gdk

Just getting the Google Glass GDK (19) running with Eclipse Java and its all up and running fine. ADB etc all good.

And now experimenting with the Compass Sample code.  One thing I would like to try and pin down is basically customising whats there - a simple thing being the Touch Menu text which is "Show A Compass".

Can that be changed? That's all I want to do!  However, `strings.xml` alters `app_name` only and the XML Trigger def of `SHOW_A_COMPASS` seems locked down somewhere. I guess that's what I am trying to discover.

Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks
Doug

Comment: Ok - its part of the SYSTEM itself: public static final VoiceTriggers.Command <br> But can it still be altered - or would that mean rooting?

Answer (score 1):

You specify the trigger command in an XML file in your resources. In compass this is [res/xml/compass_show.xml](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-compass-sample/blob/master/res/xml/compass_show.xml). In there, you will see a `<trigger>` tag, which you should change to one of the constants in [VoiceTriggers.Command](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/VoiceTriggers.Command). So if you wanted to use the voice command "Find a product" you could use something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<trigger command="FIND_A_PRODUCT" />
```

You can use your own voice commands... but only for testing purposes. Glassware that is reviewed and distributed through MyGlass must use a defined command. (You can, however, [request a voice command](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/voice-form) be included in a future Glass update. If you plan to do this, you should request it as early as possible.)

See https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice for the full details.